# Do BTLE device created by SPP using core bluetooth framework still need MFi chip to communicate over bluetooth ios?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, btle

I am having non iOS device made from SPP which I want it to communicate with iOS device using core bluetooth framework without using MFI.Is it possible or not?? if not possible then what changes should I make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use SPP without going through the MFi program.  The Core Bluetooth framework allows you to communicate with BTLE devices using the GATT profile, without MFi certification.

There are a number of BTLE devices that use a pair of attributes - one for received data and one for transmitted data - to provide data on a serial port that can be connected to an embedded micro controller

Comment: So i need to change the profile? then by using iAP profile it can be done?

Comment: Why I cannot use SPP without MFI though i am using core bluetooth framework.As some where I read that for BTLE device use of core bluetooth framework does not require MFI.

Comment: Yes, only the GATT profile is supported by Core Bluetooth - https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/GATT.aspx

Comment: Correct, Core Bluetooth and BTLE are not covered by MFi, but it only supports the GATT profile

Comment: If I want to use SPP then any how I need to use MFI? and then i could use external accessory framework also, no need to use core bluetooth framework. Am I correct?

Comment: Correct, but I believe you would need to use Bluetooth 2.1, not BTLE

Comment: For external accessory framework does it require Bluetooth 2.1? why it cannot work with any version of bluetooth?

Comment: You would need to confirm with Apple, but the MFi FAQ - https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action#1-2 states "Accessories that use only Bluetooth Low Energy (BTLE) " are not part of the MFi program.  I am not sure if this applies to BTLE using SPP, but typically if you are going to use BTLE you would just use GATT and avoid the whole MFi issue

Comment: But if I am going to use external accessary framework with all type of bluetooth not necessarily BTLE only with SPP profile then MFI is required?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62504/discussion-between-paulw11-and-jalak-patel).